# Google Maps error "'addDomListener' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, mootools

I feel like this is a fairly simple bit of code and the code being run in the iframe is taken as the example code from Google Map's docs, so it's something to do with the iframe, but I'm not sure.

In short, I'm creating an iframe, putting the Google Maps JS API in there, then loading a function into it that has the map example from their docs. I get

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addDomListener' of undefined`

Here's the JSBin link: http://jsbin.com/ucovaj/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A look into the console would have told you something like this:

*A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored*

You can't load the default-maps-script asynchronously, because it makes use of `document.write()` what can't be used after a document has finished loading.

You must load a special version in this case by adding a callback-parameter to the URL(see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API for details)

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The error I pasted above is from the console. How else would I see a JS error? :P

Comment: I'll take a look at your solution, thank you! I'm interested in how you got this error tho. It doesnt show up as that in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Still messing with it, and the map isn't quite showing up, but using the callback param fixed all the errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've only had a brief look but there is an error that you are redefining **Map** here:

```
var Map = function (opts) {
```

Does this need to be called Map? Perhaps myMap.

Answer (score 0):

I came to a similar error while playing around with Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and it's [Hello World](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) sample, as it is said in the tutorial page I added the api like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

But it gave me the message as in the title of this post, after some investigation I found that, in working samples there's another parameter passed in query string section of the api's url, which was the v for version, it wasn't mentioned that it's required but adding `v=3.exp` made it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=xxxxxxxxx&sensor=false">
</script>
```

I hope it saves someone's precious time.

Answer (score 0):

The event is generated before function and it does not recognize,
you change this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

for this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
});
```